# How to sort jqGrid when the wanted sorted field doesn't in SQL?

Tags: php, sorting, jqgrid

When we use jgGrid, like this:

```
get_items.php =>

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
//$sidx is the index row.  
//ie. $sidx = 'name';

$result = $mysql->query( $SQL ); 

header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
...
//balah balah
...

while ( $row = $mysql->fetch_array( $result ) ) {
...
//Note the getName method.
$s .= "<cell>". getName($row['name']))."</cell>";
...
};

echo $s;


function getName ( name ) {
   if ( name == 'Lane' ) return 'Brian Lane';
   if ( name == 'Kerwin' ) return 'Diane Kerwin';
   ...
   ...
}
```

Now the question is :

if I sort the jqGrid by ASC, it will show like `Diane Kerwin, Brian Lane` as `Kerwin` is before `Lane`.

How to sort the fields like `Brian Lane, Diane Kerwin` by ASC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preferred solution

It looks like only the last names are stored in the database. To be able to sort by first name in your SQL query, you'll need to update the `name` fields in the `items` table to contain both first and last names. This would be much better — keeping a separate data set embedded in your code will probably cause problems at some point later on.

---

#### If you must:

If this isn't a possibility and you must keep the `if` statements for each name, you could map over the result set to fetch the names and then sort. (The example below requires PHP >= 5.3.)

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = $mysql->query($SQL);

$rows = array();
while ( $row = $mysql->fetch_array($result) ) {
    switch ( $row['name'] ) {
        case 'Lane': $row['name'] = 'Brian Lane';
        case 'Kerwin': $row['name'] = 'Diane Kerwin';
    }

    array_push($rows, $row);
}

usort($rows, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); });
```

Comment: Yes, I must. Because the real logic is complicated so I use above example, but the essence is the same so I can't change database. The second solution seems has a problem: it can't sort correctly when the pagination.

Comment: What happens when you try to add pagination? I can't see the problem.